# Mixing default arguments in Python 2.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments

I'm trying to mix default keyword arguments, positional arguments and keyword arguments in Python 2.7. From the following code, I expect `profile=='system'`, `args==(1,2,3)` and `kwargs={testmode: True}`.

```
def bla(profile='system', *args, **kwargs):
    print 'profile', profile
    print 'args', args
    print 'kwargs', kwargs


bla(1, 2, 3, testmode=True)
```

What I get is:

```
profile 1
args (2, 3)
kwargs {'testmode': True}
```

Can this be done in Python 2.7 or do I need Python 3.x?

Comment: That can't be what you get, because you typed `testmode` and claim to have gotten `quick mode`.

Comment: I think you're mixing up your terminology here, confusing arguments with parameters, and parameters with default values with keyword-only parameters. What you've written is a keyword-or-positional parameter with a default value. It accepts the first positional arg, or the keyword arg named `profile`, or the default value `'system'` (if neither of the above). What you want is a keyword-only parameter. Python 2 doesn't have those, so you have to take it as shown in unutbu's answer. Python 3 does, but being keyword-only has nothing to do with having a default value, only being after `*args`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python2:

```
def bla(*args, **kwargs):
    profile = kwargs.pop('profile', 'system')
    print 'profile', profile
    print 'args', args
    print 'kwargs', kwargs
```

In Python3 it's possible to define [keyword-only arguments](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/):

```
def bla(*args, profile='system', **kwargs):
    print('profile', profile)
    print('args', args)
    print('kwargs', kwargs)
```

the call `bla(1, 2, 3, testmode=True)`  yields

```
profile system
args (1, 2, 3)
kwargs {'testmode': True}
```

Comment: You might want to use `pop` instead of `get`, so `profile` doesn't end up still in `kwargs`.